# How to ignore double quotes which were added when comma was added in column value in pipe delimited csv file?

Tags: sql-server

I have a **pipe delimited** csv file whose data are to be inserted into sql server.

Then I

1. Opened that file in excel and **added comma** in column values.
2. Then saved.

   Here is the data in notepad++ after adding comma.
   [image]
3. Then I bulk inserted that file into sql server.

   ```
   BULK INSERT #temp1
   FROM '\\as03\AppData\PipeDelimited.csv' 
   WITH  (
          FIRSTROW = 2 
        , FIELDTERMINATOR ='|'                      
        , ROWTERMINATOR='\n'
        , ERRORFILE ='\\as03\AppData\ErrorFiles\PipeDelimited.csv'
        , CODEPAGE = '65001'
        **strong text**, MAXERRORS =  99999999 
   )
   ```

But got the double quotes (") in first and last column values and also got two consecutive double quotes ("") where one double quote was already in file.

Here is the data inserted in sql server.
[image]

**Is where some way to insert data in sql server by ignoring double quotes that were added by excel or notepad**????

Comment: `FIELDQUOTE = '"'`?

Comment: Please, [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You tagged `PowerShell` but there isn't any PowerShell statement in your question to help you with...

Comment: _I have a pipe delimited csv file_ No you don't. Just like a tab-delimited file is TSV, a pipe-delimited file is PSV. And your original file was already encoded incorrectly - if the field data includes the `"`, `|` or linebreak characters then it should have doubled the `"` character in the field data and surrounded the field with a pair of `"` characters, i.e.: `Harry|India|"Delhi""Panta™ or ®"|9856524524`

Comment: If you need to maintain PSV format then don't let Excel near it. Excel cannot output pipe-delimited files, but it can read them in: while opening one tell it that it's a Delimited file, tick "My data has headers" and on the second page select `Other` and specify `|` as the delimiter. But when saving it you'll have to save to a tab-delimited file or comma-delimited file because Excel cannot write pipe-delimited files.

Comment: Don't forget `FORMAT = 'CSV'` as well, @JeremyLakeman .

Comment: @iRon I tagged powershell in hope of some solution to fix the quotes in csv file from powershell.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning No I don't need to maintain PSV format. Just need to insert data into sql server after adding comma in csv file with pipe  symbol as separator without the double quotes added by excel or notepad.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a non-(PowerShell)issue as it actually works fine in PowerShell:

```
$Csv = @'
Name|Country|Address|Mobile
Tom|Nepal|Kathmandu,Nardevi|98456667365
Harry|India|Delhi"Patna,™ or R|9856524524
'@ -Split '[\r?\n]'

$Csv |ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|' # Import-Csv .\PipeDelimited.csv -Delimiter '|'
```

Yields:

```
Name  Country Address            Mobile
----  ------- -------            ------
Tom   Nepal   Kathmandu,Nardevi  98456667365
Harry India   Delhi"Patna,™ or R 9856524524
```

In other words, you might simply convert your `PipeDelimited.csv` to a more common `CommaDelimited.csv` *with text indicators* like:

```
Import-Csv .\PipeDelimited.csv -Delimiter '|' |Export-Csv .\CommaDelimited.csv
```

Comment: Are these all powershell commands??? Please explain you codes. I am not getting what are you trying to do

Comment: You are giving worng input data. After adding comma data in notepadd++ are
          $Csv = @'
          Name|Country|Address|Mobile
          "Tom|Nepal|Kathmandu,Nardevi|98456667365"
          "Harry|India|Delhi""Patna,™ or R|9856524524"
          '

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73551702/edit) your question and replace the picture(s) with correct input data. I have update my answer as it actually doesn't appear to be an issue for PowerShell.

Comment: I have edited my question and replace the picture with correct input data. Actually if PowerShell is able to fix the quotes then I was planning to use those PowerShell commands in sql server using xp_cmdshell.

Comment: Using Import-Csv .\PipeDelimited.csv -Delimiter '|' |Export-Csv .\CommaDelimited.csv. Input value
"Tom|Nepal|Kathmandu,Nardevi|98456667365"
is changed into
"Tom|Nepal|Kathmandu,Nardevi|98456667365",,,
Which is not the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Your file was corrupted by editting it in Excel and saving it as a CSV.  The best solution is to not use Excel to edit such files, but rather either use scripting or a text editor (depending on the complexity - just adding a comma to one field feels easiest in a text editor).

However; if we're saying the damage is done and you need a script to fix the issues caused you could run something like this; this reads in the data as plain text, applies a regex to remove the offending quotes, then spits the result out to a copy of the file (I've written to a copy rather than back to the original so you can rollback more easily if this wasn't what you wanted).

```powershell
[string]$sourcePath = '.\PipeDelimited.csv'
[string]$outputPath = '.\PipeDelimitedCorrected.csv'
[System.Text.Encoding]$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 # based on your code page
[string[]]$data = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($sourcePath, $encoding)
$data = $data | ForEach-Object {((($_ -replace '^"', '') -replace '"$', '') -replace '""', '"')} 
    # replaces quotes at the start and end of the line with blanks, 
    # then replaces escaped double quotes with individual double quotes... 
    # it's a quick and dirty approach, but looking at your example should be sufficient
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($outputPath, $data, $encoding)
```